# Cross-Site Questions Reported

Tags: discussion

There have been others but here is a prolific one:

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/31648/arm-exercises-when-to-alternate-arms

and

[Arm exercises: when to alternate arms?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/8680/arm-exercises-when-to-alternate-arms)

What is the moderation strategy with these posts where: "I didn't get an answer I liked so I reposted the question on health/PF"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag as cross posted, and the moderators will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that was a flag reason.

Comment: It's not a listed reason, but you can put "for moderator attention", and we'll take a look at it. In this case, the question on health is looking for studies about it, rather than experiences/opinion, so after talking about it briefly with FD, I reopened it there.

Answer (score 2):

The question was different: it is not a cross-site question.

Also, the question was closed (by you, amongst others) on one of the SE site before the other question was posted here.